# System.Security.VerificationException with EF 6.0 and Oracle

Tags: oracle, entity-framework, wcf, odata

I'm trying to put together a simple oData service to access an Oracle database. I have followed this tutorial: http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/12c/r1/appdev/dotnet/EntityFrameworkWCF/index.html except I'm using my database and VB.NET and EF 6. As of June, EF 6 should be supported by Oracle.

I am able to navigate to the root URL and see all of my entities and I am able to append $metadata to the URL and see schema, but any query I try yields:

```
<m:error xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata">
<m:code/>
<m:message xml:lang="en-US">An error occurred while processing this request.</m:message>
<m:innererror>
<m:message>Operation could destabilize the runtime.</m:message>
<m:type>System.Security.VerificationException</m:type>
<m:stacktrace>
at queryable_reader(Object )
 at System.Data.Services.Providers.ReflectionServiceProvider.GetQueryRootForResourceSet(ResourceSet container)
 at System.Data.Services.Providers.ReflectionDataServiceProvider.GetQueryRootForResourceSet(ResourceSet resourceSet)
 at System.Data.Services.Providers.DataServiceProviderWrapper.GetQueryRootForResourceSet(ResourceSetWrapper resourceSet)
 at System.Data.Services.RequestUriProcessor.ComposeExpressionForEntitySet(SegmentInfo segment, IDataService service, Boolean isLastSegment, Boolean checkRights)
 at System.Data.Services.RequestUriProcessor.ComposeExpressionForSegments(IList`1 segments, IDataService service, Boolean isCrossReferencingUri)
 at System.Data.Services.RequestUriProcessor.ProcessRequestUri(Uri absoluteRequestUri, IDataService service, Boolean internalQuery)
 at System.Data.Services.DataService`1.ProcessIncomingRequestUri()
 at System.Data.Services.DataService`1.HandleRequest()
</m:stacktrace>
</m:innererror>
</m:error>
```

I have found some resources that indicate I should change my data service class to inherit from EntityFrameworkDataService instead of Data Service, but these appear to be dated and all reference alpha & beta versions and this class does not seem to exist in the release version.

My data service class looks like this:

```
Imports System.Data.Services
Imports System.Data.Services.Common
Imports System.Linq
Imports System.ServiceModel.Web
Imports System.Data.Services.Providers


Namespace FTPOrders
    Public Class WcfDataService
        Inherits DataService(Of Entities)

       ' This method is called only once to initialize service-wide policies.
        Public Shared Sub InitializeService(ByVal config As DataServiceConfiguration)

            config.SetEntitySetAccessRule("*", EntitySetRights.AllRead)
            config.SetServiceOperationAccessRule("*", ServiceOperationRights.AllRead)
            config.DataServiceBehavior.MaxProtocolVersion = DataServiceProtocolVersion.V3
            config.DataServiceBehavior.UseMetadataKeyOrderForBuiltInProviders = True
            config.UseVerboseErrors = True
            config.EnableTypeConversion = True
        End Sub

    End Class
End Namespace
```

Any ideas on eliminating this error would be greatly appreciated. I am hoping to avoid having to start over and downgrade to EF 5.

Comment: Did you have a look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/LIbrary/432cdx67(v=vs.100).aspx? Seems to be related to type safety checking.

Comment: Yes, I saw that. It doesn't appear to be the case. This is all straight generated code at this point in time. It's a vanilla project. I'm not sure I entirely understand how to go about checking for this though.

Comment: Can you show an example of a failing query?  I want to find out if you are trying to utilize `$select`.  Does it fail with the simplest query which merely appends an entity name to url?

Comment: Yes, even just an entity name or an entity name with a key in parens failed. Passing an invalid entity name or some kind of invalid query would fail with a different error indicating the query was invalid.